# encrypted data send from laravel to angular with cryptoJS

Tags: angular, laravel, api, encryption, cryptojs

I try to sending encryted data from laravel API to Angular 9.

I can encrypt the data with Crypt::encrypt in Laravel like that:

```
$to_email = $request->email;
        $dataToEncrypt = "id_ent=" . $request->ent_id . "&id_agenda=" . $request->agenda_id;
        $dataEncrypted = Crypt::encrypt($dataToEncrypt);
        $data = array('link' =>

        "http://localhost:4200/registerUser?d=" . $dataEncrypted);

        Mail::send('mailRegistrationUser', $data, function ($message) use ($to_email) {
            $message->to($to_email)
                ->subject('Créer votre compte !');

            $message->from('contact@test.com', 'Création de votre compte');
        });
```

I share the APP_KEY between front and back so they have the same key.

Everything going well and I can recover the data in my angular app like that :

```
 getEncryptedData() {
    this.encryptedData = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('d');
    if (this.encryptedData === null) {
      this.router.navigate(['/inscription']);
    }
    this.decryptedData = this.cryptoService.get(this.encryptedData);
    console.log(this.decryptedData);
  }
```

Unfortunatly, the following method :

```
this.cryptoService.get(this.encryptedData);
```

return a empty string...

Here the method in the service :

```
keys = '123abc'; //this is a exemple. I use de key from laravel...

get(value) {
    let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.keys);
    let iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.keys);
    let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key,
      {
      keySize: 128 / 8,
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }
    );

    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
```

If someone have a idea...

Comment: Laravel uses its application key to encrypt the data, thus decrypting it requires you to share the app key, which is anti-pattern. Make sure the decryption settings match the cypher specified in `/config/app.php` and config from `\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean...